# C# - Selecting from mysql database doubles the data

Tags: c#, mysql

I have data stored in mysql database and I want to get that data and write them into C# list. It does work and gets the data into my list, but for some reason it doubles the data. When I debugged, there was 36 items in the list, while there is only 18 items stored in the db...

The code for getting the data from db is:

```
string query2 = $"SELECT odgovor FROM appdb.odgovori WHERE nazivAnkete = '{selected}';";
using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query2, conn))
    {
     using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
         {
          while (reader.Read())
               {
                //Write data to string list
                answerData.Add(reader.GetString(0));
               }
          }
    }
```

What can be the cause of this weird behaviour? Am I missing something?

***EDIT***

I got it working now, thanks to the responses. The problem was that the list was used by another class at the same time. I removed it from one place and now it works just fine.

Comment: Did you clear/re-initialized the list before running this method?

Comment: @Shocky yes, I did add  answerData.Clear(); right before this method. Same problem occurs.

Comment: Are you sure you're connecting to the correct database, e.g. test or development database that may have different amount of data but same tables?

Comment: How many rows are there in database? Can you try without `where` condition and check?

Comment: @kor_ I'm 100% sure it connects to the right database. I just ran another test. Now there were 7 items total in the database, this time my code returned 8 items, so not doubled but still added one item twice. I checked the strings in list, and it double printed one string, while there is only one of that string in the db. It's really weird.

Comment: @MKR there is exactly 25 rows overall in the table.

Comment: do you have multiple threads running this code on the same answerData instance? is answerData local variable or global?

Comment: @AndriyKizym no, this code is used only once on the main thread and I have only the main thread running here. I already thought about this, but it can't be the problem, since on the second test I got only one item doubled not all of them (7 in db, got 8 in the list). I've never seen anything like that..

Comment: Have you tried printing/adding locally instead of `answerData.Add(reader.GetString(0));` in order to confirm that its not issue with `answerData`?

Comment: @MKR yes, when I add strings locally to the list it works just fine and prints the exact number of strings I added to the list..

Comment: Then perhaps you know the answer now. Must be 2 threads calling same function and adding value twice.

Comment: thats the point, if you have different results each time running the code - some randomness involved, this usually indicates threading issues

Comment: @MKR omg, yes, you guys were right, I just searched thru the whole solution for the keyword answerData and it was indeed used by another class at the same time and I forgot about it.. god, silly me. Thank you a lot MKR, Andriy and others!